# How to fix: "missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'" using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm creating a telegram bot using python-telegram-bot library and i want to include an handler that handle parameters.

Following [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Types-of-Handlers#commandhandlers-with-arguments) article i added a new handler using `pass_args=True` directive without any success

This is what i wrote so far:

```py
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import logging
[...]
def parameters(bot, update, args):
    user_says = " ".join(args)
    update.message.reply_text("You said: " + user_says)

[...]

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

    d = updater.dispatcher

    # Handlers
    d.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    d.add_handler(CommandHandler("parameters", parameters, pass_args=True))
    d.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", helper))


    # Start the bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Keep it active untile CTRL + C
    updater.idle()
```

The problem is that when i launch the `/parameter <some_text>` from telegram, the Bot gave me this error:

```
2019-06-20 20:57:19,823 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - An uncaught error was raised while processing the update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zzz/aaaa/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 333, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/home/zzz/aaaa/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 117, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
TypeError: parameters() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

What i'm doing wrong?
I'm using the latest Beta(`python-telegram-bot==12.0.0b1`) version.

Comment: I can't run your program with the code you provided, but what is <some_text>? You are successfully passing in bot and update positional arguments, but unsuccessfully passing in args.

Comment: hello you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

the solution always inside python telegram group

telegram.org/#/im?p=@pythontelegrambotgroup  give me the solution

```
 d.add_handler(CommandHandler("parameters", parameters, pass_args=True))
```

and for the function

```
def parameters(update, context):
    user_says = " ".join(context.args)
    update.message.reply_text("You said: " + user_says)
```

The args is inside the context.args

Answer (score 0):

It is probably missing parameters on parameters:

```
d.add_handler(CommandHandler("parameters", parameters(bot, update, args), pass_args=True))
```